# In third conditional sentences, if the conditional clause precedes the independent clause, should a comma precede the independent clause?

Tags: verbs, conditionals, modal-verbs, conditional-perfect

(conditional clause with past perfect + comma + independent clause containing modal auxiliary + have + past participle)

I learned this rule many years ago when I was a high school student, but I noticed there are some people who no longer use a comma in third conditional sentences. There are a few answers about third conditional sentences on this website, but they contain extra variables. The following sentence is an example of a third conditional sentence with a comma.

> If this area had been blank, it would have been intentional.

The next sentence is without a comma.

> If this area had been blank it would have been intentional.

Which one is correct?

Comment: @KannE
I agree, the first one is correct. Why would anyone intentionally omit the comma? By the way, native speakers certainly do have numbered conditionals. There are four of them numbered zero through three. I am a native speaker, and I was an English teacher for quite a while. I've chosen not to use ELL. Some of the advice given on that platform is based on what sounds natural rather than the real rules of grammar.

Comment: The numbered conditionals are for more suitable for ELL learners. I doubt if many grammarians on this site ever use the terms, or have ever heard of them.

Comment: I'd say that nowadays commas in such sentences are completely optional. They don't cue for a particular reading (sense). But they _are_ used more and more nowadays to cue for a certain style. Does the comma, where not necessary for distinguishing a sense, nevertheless  _speed up_ parsing? Does it give a slight dramatic pause? Does it help older readers to avoid gasping for breath (when the protasis is lengthy)? // As an aside, your examples exhibit garden-pathness. One looks for an overt antecedent for 'it'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth
Thank you for chiming in. Your comments always make sense and remind me that grammar rules are not as firm as the rules of mathematics. For the example sentence I presented, I prefer to use the comma to indicate a rise in intonation on the word *'blank'* followed by a brief pause before the independent clause. Also, you're absolutely right about there being no antecedent. In this case, *'it'* is *'my decision to leave the area blank'*.

Comment: @KannE
- You're right; we do make up the rules. It looks like grammar is evolving with our culture. By the way, your conditional sentence was a #1. Here's a #2... If it caught on, M-W would add it to their definition.